# Manully Deploy my aps.net web application to Azure Web app, without using Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service

I have the following:-

- I create a new Azure web app.
- Using VS 2019 i created a new Asp.net 4.5 web application which contain WCF service.
- i tried to deploy my asp.net application into azure using Visual Studio, but i failed.

  - I tried using Web Deploy:-

[image]

- I tried using ftp:-

[image]

but both approaches failed, where i got connection error. as follow:-

[image]

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
>   System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window for more
>   details. --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceledExceptions) at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
>   CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
>   Microsoft.WebTools.Publish.PublishService.VsWebProjectPublish.c_DisplayClass43_0.b3()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke() at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute() --- End of stack trace from
>   previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Microsoft.Publish.Framework.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel.d_213.MoveNext()
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.<---
>
> ```
> System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.
> ```

so my question if i can manually deploy my asp.net web application to azure web app without relying on VS? for example using power-shell or from azure portal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Here's one way using Azure CLI:

```
az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group myResourceGroup --name <app_name> --src <filename>.zip
```

You can also access Kudu portal (https://your-web-app.scm.azurewebsites.net) and upload the zip file:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/benjaminperkins/deploy-to-an-azure-app-service-using-kudu-and-a-zip-file

Comment: can you let me know how i can run this command? using powershell?

Comment: You can install it by running Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://aka.ms/installazurecliwindows -OutFile .\AzureCLI.msi; Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList '/I AzureCLI.msi /quiet' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-windows?view=azure-cli-latest

Comment: but you can also manually upload the zip using kudu portal too (same result)

Comment: ok i try running this command `az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group "OurCompanySharePoint" --name "OurCompnayTestRER" --src "C:\WebApplication5.zip"`.. but i got this error `ResourceGroupNotFound - Resource group 'OurCompanySharePoint' could not be found.`.. although the group name for the web app is correct.. any advice

Comment: have you authenticate to your account with Az login? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest#az-login

Comment: now i have multiple subscriptions as follow `Az account list --o table` i got `Pay as you go ` & `Microsoft Azure`

Comment: you need to select your subscription using az account set --subscription